# How to find the name of a list

Tags: python, string, list

I want to find the name of a list,  how can i do that in python ?

This is my code:

```
ab = "the sky is blue" #in my code i don't know what text is in ab 

#others lists...
bannana = ["white", "red", "blue"]
tomato = ["red", "shiny", "grey"]
peach = ["séché", "mure", "moisi"]
spicybannana = ['uigyig','iuig','iug']
#other lists...

l1 = [bannana, tomato, peach]

randomlist = randrange(0, len(l1))

for i in l1[randomlist]:   
   if i in ab:
      #if list name contain 'bannana':
```

Comment: Store the lists in a dictionary with the list name being the key and the list being the value, problem solved

Comment: `if l1[randomlist] == bannana:` Would compare to see if they are the same lists, is that what you're after?

Comment: @Jkdc no because i want to know if the current list name contain 'bannana' because i have others lists named bannana... i want to match them all

Comment: @TimCastelijns ok i see, but i use randrange to get a random list, so i now have to generate a random string that is in l1 ?

Comment: Use `random.choice` and a list of names for the list - see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @Tim_Castelijns suggestion - just store the lists in a dictionary:

```
other_lists = {
    'bannana': ["white", "red", "blue"],
    'tomato': ["red", "shiny", "grey"],
    'peach': ["séché", "mure", "moisi"]
}

randomlist = random.choice(['bannana', 'tomato', 'peach'])
for i in other_lists[randomlist]:
    if i in ab:
        if 'bannana' == randomlist:  # use 'in' for substring
            ...
```